# Unwanted Additional Application Instance

Tags: blend-files

Somehow I ended up with a 'duplicate' instance. I must have accidentally pressed some key combination to get this. They appear to have different layouts (Check the bottom of the screen capture). Though I guess it doesn't prevent me from working on my file, I'd prefer to get back to working on a single instance.

Anyone have any experience with this issue?

Thanks,

Andy

[image]

Comment: You just opened another Blender instance and opened a file within that instance (not visible if same or not but it's not important). You should decide which instance is the one you're working in and close another one if you don't need it (looks like you don't). This is not Blender related problem.

Comment: Every time I close out the file and reopen Blender, the 2 instances are there yet again.

You're right though. Previously I'd always saved the file before closing out. I tried closing out one of the instances and then saved the file before closing the second and upon reopening Blender I've got a single instance now. Thanks